# Elliptic curve with no points in a number field

Tags: number-fields, elliptic-curves

The following is probably well-known (I'd appreciate a link):

for a field $K$ that is a finite extension of the field of rational numbers, give a polynomial $f(x,y) ∈ Q[x,y]$ of the form $y^2 − x^3 − Ax − B$, s.t. $4A^3 + 27B^2 ≠ 0$ and $f(x,y)$ has no zero in $K^2$.

Thank you -
Albertas

Comment: An elliptic curve over $K$ is by definition a projective curve of genus 1 _with a distinguished point over $K$_.

Comment: I'll assume you mean "genus 1 curve" not "elliptic curve".  MO's own Pete Clark has various papers with much stronger results than this, for example "There are genus one curves of every index over every number field" - Crelle 594 (2006), 201-206.

Comment: Or, if you mean that there exists $E/K$ with $E(K)=\{0\}$, this is a (recent) theorem of Mazur and Rubin (http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3709)

Comment: Pardon the ambiguity. I meant:

for a field $K$ that is a finite extension of the field of rational numbers, give a polynomial $f(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q}[x, y]$ of the form $y^2 - x^3 - Ax - B$, s.t. $4A^3 + 27B^2 \neq 0$ and $f(x, y)$ has no zero in $K^2$.

Thank you very much for the comments. I cannot infer an answer to the question so far. The last comment seems to suggest it may be not known/be a recent matter.

Comment: I edited the question in order to disambiguate it.

Comment: @Albertas: perhaps I am missing something, but Theorem 1.1 in the paper quoted by Tim Dokchister will give an elliptic curve with just the 'distinguished point' and not other point. Now, for each elliptic curve one can get an isomorphic one being defined via an equation of your form (Weierstrass form). There will be the 'point at infinity' but no other one, thus no 'affine' one. That is to say the equation has no solution. 

Comment: The curve in the Mazur-Rubin theorem is defined over K; the proposer wants a curve defined over Q. So as far as I can see the problem is still open.

Comment: If $K/\Bbb Q$ is a cyclic extension of prime degree then it basically follows from the discussion of Remark 7.1 of the Mazur-Rubin paper, just take $r = 0$. 

Further results might be possible with a little work. For Galois extensions, the number of rational representations of Gal$(K/Q)$ will play a role, see Lemma 7.2.

Comment: It is not very difficult to show that for a prime number $q$ that splits completely in $K$ and any integer $a$ that is not a square modulo $q$, the curve defined by $y^2 = qx^2 + a$ does not have points over $K$. One then can obtain a genus one curve defined by $y^2 = qx^4 + a$ that has no points over $K$. The projective curve $y^2z^2 = qx^4 + az^4$ then would have precisely one point over $K$, namely, $(x : y : z) = (0 : 1 : 0)$. 


Comment: It is not clear to me, however, if one can obtain from the above a curve of the form $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ for some integers $A, B$ that had no points over $K$. 